# Передвижение объекта

Tags: actionscript

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажите куда смотреть, что проверить?

Сделал простенькое передвижение, но при многократном использовании начинает ужасно тормозить. Попробуйте по передвигать пешками раз 15. С чем это может быть связано?
Пробовал делать по событию `Enter_frame` и `Timer`. Разницы никакой. Тормозит так же.

```
private function run_Peshka(event:Event):void {
        _incrimentForCount++;

        if (_incrimentForCount == _countForRun){
                _Peshka.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runUnit);

            }
        else {
                _Peshka.x += _XSpeed;
                _Peshka.y += _YSpeed;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Код выкладывайте и будет вам счастье...

Comment: Заколебся двигать, одна пешка улетела далеко за экран, но ничего не тормозит.

Comment: у меня вообще ничего не передвигается)